# Raspbian: Start X11VNC on boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, vnc

I'm running Raspbian on an RPi2 and I'm trying to start `x11vnc` on boot but I can't get it to work.

`x11vnc` is working but the autostart is not. I created `/home/pi/.config/autostart/x11vnc.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[DESKTOP ENTRY]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=X11VNC
Comment=
Exec=x11vnc -forever -usepw -display :0 -ultrafilexfer
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

but it's not executing the command on startup...

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked but I copied the x11vnc.desktop file from /usr/share/applications/ and modified it to look similar to the contents above and it seemed to fix the problem...

Comment: How did you modify it? Your answer is useless without that information.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat .config/autostart/x11vnc.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=X11VNC Server
Comment=Share this desktop by VNC
Exec=x11vnc -gui -usepw -forever -loop
Icon=computer
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
#StartupWMClass=x11vnc_port_prompt
Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;

Answer (score 4):

To start `x11vnc` at boot (not from the user profile) it would be better to add the following line to the `/etc/rc.local` (before `exit 0`) <sup>[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=106960)</sup>

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

note that by using `-fbauth` you will first need to store the password.  Issue this command a single time.  Change "somepassword" to whatever you want

```
/usr/bin/x11vnc -storepasswd somepassword /etc/x11vnc.pass
```